# JSON опция JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS

Tags: java, json, jackson

> use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS option will serialize minimal
> relative package path. For example, for supertype
> "com.logicbig.example.Shape", and concrete type
> "com.logicbig.example.shapes.Circle", only ".shapes.Circle" would be
> included; for "com.logicbig.example.shapes.impl.Rectangle" only
> ".shapes.impl.Rectangle" would be included and for
> "com.logicbig.example.Square" only ".Square" will be included.

Я не могу понять, как опция понимает, что минимальный относительный путь пакета именно такой? В примере про `Shape`, почему, например, не `.example.shapes.Circle`, а именно `.shapes.Circle`? Относительно чего выбирается путь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимальный путь класса выбирается путем сравнения двух классов - суперкласса и подкласса.

В данном примере суперкласом является `com.logicbig.example.Shape`, подклассом которого является `com.logicbig.example.shapes.Circle`. У них есть общий путь `com.logicbig.example`, который удаляется при сериализации. Поэтому остается только `Shape` и `.shapes.Circle`.